# Where should the list-style CSS property go?

Tags: html, css

Should the list styling properties go on the `ul` element or the `li` elements?

I have never seen lists with different little icons to the left of them (within the same ul), but I have seen the property used on both elements before in my travels.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should go on the ul/ol, cf. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#list-style

**Edit**: Near the bottom ( http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style ) you will find a discussion of the issue. It boils down to:

> Inheritance will transfer the 'list-style' values from OL and UL elements to LI elements. This is the recommended way to specify list style information.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_list-style.asp),

> The list-style property is a shorthand
>   property for setting all the
>   properties for a list in one
>   declaration.

```
ul
{
    list-style: disc outside
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put it on the `ul`/`ol`. If you'd put it on the `li`, it would apply to both ordered and unordered lists, which is probably not what you want (the numbering would disappear).

Comment: Well, that depends on how you express the qualifier (e.g. `.something li` vs. `.something ul li`)